# which version should i use to connect postgresql9.4.24

Tags: postgresql, pg

I attemp to use pgadmin v5, but it tips me version is not correct,Can you tel me which pgadmin
version should i use to connect postgresql？thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

What is incorrect is the version of PostgreSQL, not the version of pgAdmin. Use something supported, ideally the latest version.

Comment: The version of postgresql is selected by company but not me,thank u anywherw

Comment: Then select a different company.